# Cargo build broke after using VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo

For a while I have been editing my Rust program with Pycharm Professional. However, I was curious and experimented with VS Code. At first my project was compiling and running. However, it suddenly started throwing a pretty wild error on **cargo build** and **cargo run** (while **cargo check** is fine), even in cmd outside of VS Code:

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1104
= note: "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "C:\\rust\\book\\target\\debug\\deps\\book.1apvyby1qhuehv3.rcgu.o" "C:\\rust\\book\\target\\debug\\deps\\book.1cw7xmk0cjjg5uln.rcgu.o" "C:\\rust\\book\\target\\debug\\deps\\book.1e8ho0j4rykowhcr.rcgu.o" "C:\\rust\\book\\target\\debug\\deps\\book.1g2fbveo2gp7bxds.rcgu.o"
..............
..............
= note: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\rust\book\target\debug\deps\book.exe'
```

book is the name of my project.
I am on Windows 10, System Type: x64-based PC.
VS Code version 1.63.2

Comment: Try running `cargo clean` to remove the existing build artifacts.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a shot

Comment: Make sure that your program is not running when you call `cargo build` or `cargo run`, and wait a little bit after it has stopped before calling `cargo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes VSCode file watcher watches the files in `target/`, that is not good.
So open the Settings, search for exclude, and in all "list-like" cofigurations add `**/target/**`, do a `cargo clean` and restart VSCode. This should fix this and future problems

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove the directory, and redownload the whole project(used Git).